# SQL Query within VS TableAdapter Query Configuration Wizard

Tags: sql, visual-studio, tableadapter

I am trying to write an SQL query within Visual Studio TableAdapter Query Wizard

My SQL query is:

```
    DECLARE @SQL varchar(255);

SET @SQL = ' SELECT * FROM dbAddress WHERE 1 = 1'

IF @ApexLine1 = ''
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND addLine1 IS NULL '
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND addLine1 = ''' + @ApexLine1 + ''''
    END

IF @ApexLine2 = ''
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND addLine2 IS NULL '
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND addLine2 = ''' + @ApexLine2 + ''''
    END

IF @ApexLine3 = ''
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND addLine3 IS NULL '
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND addLine3 = ''' + @ApexLine3 + ''''
    END

IF @ApexZip = ''
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND addPostCode IS NULL '
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND addPostCode = ''' + @ApexZip + ''''
    END

IF @ApexCity = ''
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND addLine4 IS NULL '
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND addLine4 = ''' + @ApexCity + ''''
    END

IF @ApexProv = ''
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND addLine5 IS NULL '
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND addLine5 = ''' + @ApexProv + ''''
    END

EXEC(@SQL)
```

I get the error:

'The Declare SQL contruct or statement is not supported'

If I remove the Declare statement I get error:

'The Set SQL construct or statement is not supported'

Is there a work around for this?

Thanks.

Comment: NeverNEVER **NEVER** build query strings like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything like this:

```
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND addLine1 = ''' + @ApexLine1 + ''''
```

is ***EVIL***.  Don't do it.  Variables like @ApexLine1 could contain *anything*, even something like this:

> ';DROP TABLE dbAddress--

Think very carefully about what would happen if someone entered something like that in your Address Line 1 field.  The only correct solution here is to use the built-in `sp_executesql` stored procedure. Learn it, use it.

Aside from that, I think at least part of your problem might be that your @SQL variable is only 255 characters.  It's easily possible your query is running out of space.

Comment: I am not too worry about the SQL injection issues as the parameters are not being acquired from a textbox or anything. They are being pulled from another database in the code behind. Plus this is a local intranet application that no one outside of our firm has access to. This is just a test query, the 255 characters will be lifted once it is working, but that is not the issue.

Comment: It doesn't matter if they're pulled from another database.  It's still an injection risk (2nd order injection), because _that_ database was likely populated by hand somewhere.  And "local intranet" is never an excuse - most attacks are inside jobs.   Even if those were valid excuses, why not do it right?  It's no harder.  What you are doing with that query is just plain **wrong**.

Comment: Point taken. I will take the necessary steps to fix. Thank you.